# AttributeError: Label instance has no call method

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a test program using Tkinter, but I'm running into some trouble.

I'm trying to make a Rock, Paper, Scissors game on which the users always loses, but I get "Label has no call instance", here's the code:

```
#Rock papers & scissor

import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):

    def setLabel(self):

        entry2 = self.entry.get()   

        if entry2 == "paper":
            self.l1(App, text="Scissors, you loose!")
        elif entry2 == "Paper":
            self.l1(text="Scissors, you loose!")
        elif entry2 == "PAPER":
            self.l1(text="Scissors, you loose!")
        elif entry2 == "rock":
            self.l1(text="Paper, you loose!")
        elif entry2 == "Rock":
            self.l1(text="Paper, you loose!")
        elif entry2 == "ROCK":
            self.l1(text="Paper, you loose!")
        elif entry2 == "Scissors":
            self.l1(text="Rock, you loose!")
        elif entry2 == "scissors":
            self.l1(text="Rock, you loose!")
        elif entry2 == "SCISSORS":
            self.l1(text="Rock, you loose!")
        elif entry2 == "scissor":
            self.l1(text="Rock, you loose!")
        elif entry2 == "Scissor":
            self.l1(text="Rock, you loose!")
        elif entry2 == "SCISSOR":
            self.l1(text="Rock, you loose!")
        else:
            self.l1(text="wat")

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Go!", command=self.setLabel)
        self.l1 = tk.Label(self, text="Waiting...")
        self.entry.pack()
        self.btn.pack()
        self.l1.pack()


App().mainloop()
App().minsize(300, 100)
App().title("Test")
```

Comment: Why not entry2.lower() ? It's more confortable :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems:

1. `self.l1(text='mytext')` is incorrect. When you put the parentheses right after `self.l1`, you're trying to call that label like it's a function, but it's not a function. You have to call that label's `config()` method.
2. At the bottom, you create an `App` object and loop it... then you create another, and another. Create one, save a reference, and then work with it.
3. Your `if` branch was larger than it could be.
4. The `mainloop()` call should be at the end.
5. You misspelled "lose" (yes, that counts).

The following fixes these problems:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):

    def setLabel(self):

        entry2 = self.entry.get().lower()
        if entry2.startswith('p'):
            self.l1.config(text="Scissors, you lose!")
        elif entry2.startswith('r'):
            self.l1.config(text="Paper, you lose!")
        elif entry2.startswith('s'):
            self.l1.config(text="Rock, you lose!")
        else:
            self.l1.config(text="wat")

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Go!", command=self.setLabel)
        self.l1 = tk.Label(self, text="Waiting...")
        self.entry.pack()
        self.btn.pack()
        self.l1.pack()

app = App()
app.minsize(300, 100)
app.title("Test")
app.mainloop()
```